# td-ameritrade-client Java kandi project usability?

Tags: java, stockquotes

Is the td-ameritrade-client Java kandi project functioning and currently useable?  With apologies, I'm new to consuming kandi projects.  My needs are pretty simple and from what I've read this should do it all, but I'm having difficulties getting up and running.  Before I spend too much time only to find out it is incomplete or defunct, I'm hoping to get some feedback.

Comment: This is tantamount to asking for a recommendation which is off-topic on StackOverflow.  My advice would be to look at the project's history and the issue tracker ... and do some google searches ... and then make your own judgement.  If you are having difficulties, it might be more productive to ask about those difficulties and/or raise issues for those issues.  (It could be that you are "doing it wrong" or that the problems are due to bugs that are known ... or that haven't been reported yet.)

Comment: *"This is tantamount to asking for a recommendation which is off-topic on StackOverflow."* - Or it is asking for opinion-based answers which is also off-topic.

Comment: Note that the project had commits last August so it clearly isn't abandoned.  Other measures of project health include the number of outstanding pull requests, and the existence of significant forks.  But ultimately, no outsider can give you an object prediction of what will happen in the future.